# TypeError: input.includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

So I'm making a simple script to check if an input field contains "@" but whenever I run the code below I get the following error: TypeError: input.includes is not a function.

The code:

```
function check() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    if(input.includes("@")) {
        alert("Success!!");
    }
}
```

and here is my html if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>opdracht3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="check()"></button>
    </form>

    <script src="opdracht3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the value of the input. Add `.value` to your code:

```js
function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');

  if (input.value.includes("@")) {
    alert("Success!!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="check()"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have no clue how I didn't think of this, thanks!